# Run only one task and handler from ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

How can I run a single task from an Ansible playbook and the handler that gets notified when that task completes successfully, while skipping all other tasks in the relevant playbook?

Currently I execute the following:

```
ansible-playbook --start-at-task "task1" --step -K -i hosts playbook.yml
```

and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> after the task has finished. This will also skip the handler however.

I know I can add a tag to the task and use that, as in [How to run only one task in ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23945201/how-to-run-only-one-task-in-ansible-playbook), but I would prefer being able to do this without adding a tag. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly why you want to avoid adding a tag? Because one can think of several methods, but they all would be more cumbersome than adding a tag.

Comment: Simply because it seems too cumbersome. Also, given that there is a direct option to skip previous tasks, it would seem to make sense for there to also be a direct option to skip later tasks. Based on the answers here this seems not to be the case however, so I'm tempted to accept the answer of Cedric Morent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently nothing coming with ansible-playbook to allow you to run a single task, like `--task`. Thus, to me, the tag along with the `--tags` option is your best solution here.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to run a separate role (from `roles/` dir):

```
ansible -i stage.yml -m include_role -a name=create-os-user localhost
```

and a separate task file:

```
ansible -i stage.yml -m include_tasks -a file=tasks/create-os-user.yml localhost
```

If you externalize tasks from role to root `tasks/` directory (reuse is achieved by `import_tasks: ../../../tasks/create-os-user.yml`) you can run it independently from playbook/role.

Comment: Note that this [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24598849/3332686) correctly load template files. So `roles/foo/tasks/bar.yml` can't find its templates in `roles/foo/templates/baz.j2`.

Comment: @proc Sure. Search path is somewhat mystical in Ansible. When you start heavily `include` / `import` it becomes difficult to understand: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html